# How to ship a documentation wiki with an OS web app

Tags: documentation

For an open source web application, there should be documentation. Keeping such documentation in a Wiki seems to be an desirable approach because various users can easily contribute to it, explaining their use cases and how they get them done. However, a small number of users have their instances running on an intranet not connected to the internet. So it should be possible to build in a hardcopy of the current wiki state into the application, as read-only fall-back, to provide links from the web application into the wiki (to the public wiki normally, but configurable to a local copy as well). These users should not require do do a complicated set-up of a wiki web application. They must not get hold of the password hashes of the public wiki of course, so copying a database dump around (without whatever kind of post-processing it) isn’t a sensible solution. For community reasons (mainly German) the wiki should support translators (like notifications to editors of an article, if another translation of the same article changed).

[The web application](https://github.com/kitodo/kitodo-production) is in Java / Tomcat (currently 7), and requires a MySQL database, so these requirements are already provided and do not create additional work to be set up.

Are there approaches in the open source community have proven their worth to

- provide an easily, for everyone editable documentation
- which can simply be shipped as offline copy with a web application
- and support some translation feature?

Answer (score 2):

> Are there approaches in the open source community have proven their worth to
>
> - provide an easily, for everyone editable documentation
> - which can simply be shipped as offline copy with a web application
> - and support some translation feature?

This would be called wikipedia, would it?

Similarly, there is a project called [Dokuwiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org) that might be more appropriate from a smaller scale wiki and was originally designed AFAICR for software documentation...

Comment: *This would be called wikipedia, would it?* Do you mean wikimedia, the software that runs the wikipedia encyclopedia?

Comment: @Zimmi48 yes, and as always, you are correct :)